# sudden jump in value when using short int

Tags: c, type-conversion

I am trying to run this code where i use short int.

```
int main() {
    short int i=0;
    while(++i)
        printf("%u\n", i);
}
```

Ouput (using short int):

```
 1     
 2
 3...
 32767
 4294934528
 .
 .
 4294967295(last value)
```

why is there sudden jump in value after 32767 any explanations??

I am using linux(32 bit) os.

Comment: You are causing integer overflow, so this results in **undefined behvaiour**.

Comment: You are also specifying `%u` (i.e. `unsigned int`), but supplying a `signed short`.  This also results in **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: Also, watch your printf conversion specifiers.  `%u` will print an unsigned in.  `%hd` would be more suitable for a (signed) short int.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The short actually gets promoted to an int. I'm not sure whether the behavior in the face of the sign difference is standard-defined, implementation-defined, or undefined, though.

Comment: @user2357112: That's true, it does get promoted to `signed int`.

Comment: yaa i now realize i used `%u` for signed; making it `unsigned short` helps now and it prints till 65535.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior. Your program pushes `i` beyond the bounds of what can be stored in a `short`, so the program is free to do absolutely anything.

Answer (score 0):

A signed short ranges from -32768 to 32767 and an unsigned short ranges from 0 to 65535. So you are exceeding data size for signed `int short`.